# What high-level enemies respawn in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands

Much like [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3450/reach-level-61-in-borderlands)'s author, I'm interested in gaining good XP at a high level. But rather than doing challenges (which often get done in the course of normal playing, especially the *'kill X of Y'* type) I'd prefer to do it specifically by fighting enemies.

George Stocker mentioned in his answer that Motorhead respawns every 15 minutes, but surely he can't be the only unique enemy/boss who respawns. Skyscraper giving 23k XP would be great but as far as I know he's a one-off. It seems that an exhaustive list of respawning enemies would be quite useful.

Is there a list of farmable enemies, and where to find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All enemies respawn when you exit/reenter the game (with the possible exception of the destroyer).  Some respawn if you simply leave the area (such as Crawmerax).  If you have the Secret Armory of General Knoxx DLC, I would suggest farming crawmerax (best experience, and the only way to reach max level of 69).  The added bonus is he also drops a lot of high level loot, including pearlescent weapons.

Comment: what about quest enemies, like SkyScraper? Since you can't re-do quests, how do they respawn? Do you just drive/walk around their areas and hope they respawn?

Comment: @Alex yes, they should be in the vicinity

Comment: great to know, thanks. Would it be a valid question to ask for a list of big quest enemies and their locations then? e.g., the rakk hive, motorhead, mothrakk, and so on?

Comment: @Alex absolutely